# SpringBoot External Configuation

Tags: spring-boot-configuration

I am trying to keep External configuration in Spring Boot Project.
So I have achieved this using
a) Placing config at Git
b) Creating one config-server.
c) APplication get the config from config server.

But can I achieve this WITHOUT using External Config server?
I mean can't my application directly access configuration from GIT?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Spring Cloud Config, it supports having the server and client in the same app, which is what you're trying to achieve. See this thread:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/100